# Dataframe.sum() can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I'm facing an issue when trying to sum a particular column in a dataframe. Why the sum function only able to concatenate str and not float?

```
    for symbol in crypto_pair:

        #retrieve data from binance
        data_new = retrieve_binance_data(symbol=symbol)
        data_sorted = differiate_rsi(data_new, currency=symbol)
        Total = (data_sorted['Profit'].sum())
```

> C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:/Users/andyq/PycharmProjects/BinanceTrading/testenvironmentbinance.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/andyq/PycharmProjects/BinanceTrading/testenvironmentbinance.py",
> line 676, in 
> Total = (data_sorted['Profit'].sum())   File "C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 11182, in stat_func
> min_count=min_count,   File "C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
> line 3891, in _reduce
> return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py",
> line 69, in _f
> return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py",
> line 493, in nansum
> the_sum = values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum)   File "C:\Users\andyq\PycharmProjects\BinanceTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py",
> line 38, in _sum
> return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where) TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: For reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html, do a df.dtypes, that will show what are the data types of columns and then you can convert to convinient data type using this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: i realised that that are columns in profit that i appended "", so when i change it to 0. It worked, however on the excel it will not look nice. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry I dont follow the excel part.

Comment: @AndyQuek, it looks like you have mixed type in column ``Profit`` try casting to same type ```data_sorted['Profit'].astype(float)```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using a special function. I am sharing a similar example.

```
def sumSpecial(x):
    try:
        f = float(x)
        return f
    except Exception as e:
        return 0
z = [1,0, "", 0, "0.5"]
s = pd.Series(z)
s1 = s.agg(sumSpecial).sum()
print(s1)
```